# Can you use linear regression to predict individual player performance from team performance?

Tags: regression, linear

Imagine you have performance scores for each player on a soccer team using some sort of ranking system. You then group these player scores into the teams they play for, then average the player scores to calculate a "team performance" score (assuming here that better players mean a better team).

If you plot the individual performance on one axis and team performance on the other axis, a linear relationship is observed, and the data passes other assumptions of linear regression.

Is linear regression an appropriate modelling approach to use here, to predict individual performance from team performance?

I saw this approach in a [paper](https://web.holycross.edu/RePEc/fek/Session10.4-Parshakov.pdf) (page 7) and was interested in this seemingly "circular" connection of the variables, how the dependent variable is so directly linked to the the independent variable. Is there a name for this type of approach?

Comment: [Perhaps related](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/592535/can-predictive-models-make-predictions-for-individuals-or-only-for-groups/592536)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Predicting individual performance on game A given team performance on game A doesn't seem like a predictive problem as much as solving a system of equations.

I don't see a problem using linear (or non-linear!) regression to predict individual performance on game A given team performance on game B, since your team's past performance is a function of your performance.

Whether the function you are trying to model is "aggregating things" or "individualizing things," there is nothing circular going on, you are simply modeling a function. The more directly linked your input variables are to your output variables, the better!

With all this said, in the paper you are referring to, I think team performance refers to "the quality of the team" **not including** the individual player. When you have good teammates, you play better (because there are better team dynamics, because you don't want to let them down, etc...). The team you play in can affect your performance, but it is not a function of your performance.

Reference from the article:

> The first pool of variables represents the team quality. The first indicator (the average team rating except for the observed player) serves as a proxy for the team environment and can be a source to improve individual HC.

Comment: Great, thanks @pip.pip. This has helped me better articulate the question I want to ask: How does the performance of a team impact on a player, and the opposite, how does the performance of an individual impact on a team. Say your average team buys a superstar player, how can you show the impact of the player on the team (do they improve the performance) or the impact of the team on the player (does the team make the individual worse)?

Comment: With that said do you have any example systems of equations you think could be applicable in this situation?